# data is loaded but assets are not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

Im new to this and I'm using codeigniter. The problem is on my update page, I can update a user but im having trouble with its UI because its not displaying properly but the data is there. All pages are okay excluding this one. I guess it has something to do with my link or the function. Please help.

This is my edit link. `http://localhost/project/users/edit/1` and it goes to my update page loading all the data but not loading the assets/ui. really having trouble fixing this.

This is my controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['record'] =  $this->user_model->getusers();
        $this->load->view('user_page', $data);
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $data['record']=$this->user_model->getid();
        $this->load->view('user_update',$data);
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $data = array(
                       'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                       'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                       'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                       'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                    );
        $this->user_model->update($data);
        redirect('users');
    }
}
```

And this is my model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_Model extends CI_Model
{

    function getusers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('users');   
        return $query->result();
    }

    function getid()
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function update($data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('users',$data);
    }
}?>
```

All of my styles are like this.

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And for js

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: We don't know how do you call your CSS, but it should be done like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css"/>` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style.css');?>"/>` or something similar regarding location of file. Notice slash in front of assets in first case. That way you are avoiding relative path and make settings (also relative, but) to public root folder.

Comment: @Tpojka, I've update my post. Okay, i'll try that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you've really have specified this code in all your links for your images, stylesheets, javascripts. `<?php base_url();?>assets`

Double check it and let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've updated your .htaccess file to remove the "index.php" page from the path based on your edit link: `http://localhost/project/users/edit/1`

If you're using the CodeIgniter documentation's [provided .htaccess rules](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), add 'assets' to the `RewriteCond` so that links to your assets aren't re-routed through index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You also tried updating your links to `<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and `<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`?